# What is acceptable grammar for musical analysis and appreciation. How to talk about music?

Tags: analysis

When I talk or write about written or performed music I very consciously avoid using terms like "good" and "bad".

I will say whether I *like* something or not, and then try to say *why*, in terms of structure or harmony or inventiveness or technique or whatever.

Is it ever OK to say that some music really is "bad" and that other music is "good"?

Or do people say "good" and "bad" when they actually mean "I do like this" or "I don't like that".

Comment: Grammar? I'd like to vote to close but I'm not sure which reason to give. / Have you figured out what authors' writing on music you like and dislike?  Who is your audience?

Comment: idk about 'politically-correct grammar' in music analysis, but I do know a very famous A&R man who had the door on his cassette machine modified so that when he pressed eject it would drop the tape straight in the bin underneath, closely followed by the box & any covering letter - to be later sorted by his assistant, whose job it was to send all the 'thanks, but no thanks' letters back to the hopeful but unlistenable artistes ;))

Comment: Yes. Also no. To all of your questions. It depends on the people and the context. It also depends on how you want to come across. It extremely subjective.

Comment: OK, suppose I hear you perform and tell you afterwards that honestly it was bad. How do you reply? Why wasn't it bad?

Comment: If it was bad enough to tell them it was bad, you find an excuse to leave early. It's pretty tough to tell someone you know, "Don't give up your day job." It's slightly worse than having to try tell your mum her last ditch attempt to use up the xmas turkey in a curry was inedible… she will eventually forgive you. She also knew it wasn't going to be great. If your friend has been sweating on a hot stage for the past two hours, he's not going to want to hear the bad news… ever. There is no 'polite' way to tell someone their band sucks.

Comment: How do I reply? “Thanks for coming and for your feedback”. One thing I like about negative feedback is it’s much more likely to be honest

Comment: Do you have an actual case to consider? From the way to worded the question it seems obvious you know what constructive criticism and personal taste are.

Comment: You may not like this answer, but you should take a music appreciation class. This is exactly what they teach you.

Comment: One form of "objectively bad" is when performers are unable to realize the music they intend to create due to lack of skill/practice or intoxication etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a profitable line of inquiry, but expressed oddly. I'll try to answer the spirit of the question before nitpicking about the wording.

Of course there's nothing wrong with identifying music that you, personally, like or dislike. It's also rarely as simple as that—I "appreciate" *Wozzeck*, but I'd be worried about myself if I *enjoyed* it. It can also be very useful to ask yourself *what* you like or dislike about a musical experience.

The trouble is when we try to project our personal subjective reactions and treat them as universal, objective realities. This leads to phrases like "Great Music" (with the capitalizations audible in the enunciation), "High Art" (or indeed "Art" vs not-art), and "___ is not music" (rap, country, disco, emo, etc.). This betrays a worldview that either assumes that everyone thinks like me, or realizes that they might not but decides they don't matter, or at the worst, dreams of forcing the whole world to think like me. This of course gets beyond musical topics—this kind of thinking is detrimental to literary criticism, history, ethnography, and even hard sciences, mathematics, etc.

(In case this self-centric ideology isn't a clear enough proof that "Great Music," "High Art," etc. are bad ideas that we should want to escape: Consider that, when I think this way, I limit my experience and shut myself off from entire worlds of music. Also, such outlooks have real harm, whether intentional or not. Decisions get made about who to give grants, who to record, whose music to use in your tv show or ad. Colonial governments have pointed to the "primitive" musics of entire cultures as one more cultural excuse for their subjugation, when in fact they simply never bothered to study and understand them. When we confuse our outlook on the universe with universal truths, we arm ourselves to destroy what we can't see.)

But it sounds from your comment as if you're thinking about a narrower context—not so much judging whole genres and practices, but about how to offer constructive criticism to a musician. It *is* true that specific genres, practices, and music-cultures can create their own rules and rubrics—while it might be hard to say that reggae is good or bad, it might be easier to say that a given song is a good or bad reggae song.

Even then, it gets messy. For one thing, unless the parameters are *very* narrow, you might get sidetracked into definitions of what *is* good or bad within your context (what *does* make a good reggae song?). You might fight all day about who gives the "best" performance of a Rachmaninov piano concerto.

Further, in constructive criticism, it's seldom helpful to use words like "good" and "bad" even when the field is clear-cut and objective. I'm not an Olympic diving coach, but if I were I probably wouldn't even tell my divers "that was a bad dive." For one thing, there's no actionable information there, just judgement (note, "that was a good dive" is equally unhelpful). It's much better to set clear goals and talk about whether they were met.

In the performing arts, those goals are less clear and less measurable. But they generally come down to: communicating what you intend to communicate. Do you *mean* for your song to make the audience cringe? To swoon? To run screaming? To dance uncontrollably? Is your song meant simply to bare your own soul? *Does it?* If your performance doesn't do what you want it to do, then never mind good or bad—it wasn't a *successful* performance. The goal is to identify what worked and why, and what didn't and why, and that's actionable.

---

Now, linguistic nitpicking:

- You ask about what's "acceptable." That's not really the point. If your thoughts are worth sharing, then as with performance, the question is whether your thoughts are useful and effective. If your main concern is whether others will censure you for how you express them then... well, it turns into its own form of performance art, and you can either piss people off on purpose, or keep quiet out of a kind of stage fright. Unless someone is grading a paper you've written, don't worry about "acceptable," just about "profitable."
- Grammar? I wouldn't be a very good grammarian if I could restrain myself from pointing out that we're not really talking about grammar here, but about vocabulary and actual intent. But that would be annoying and un-profitable of me, so of course I won't.
- Reading between the lines, it sounds less like you're trying to find how to profitably talk about music and more like you're trying to find arguments to shut down those who call it "good" or "bad." That's criticism of criticism, and as such falls under the same recursive rules: Don't just dismiss others' practices, and try to make your communication profitable. Oh, and the other big rules unmentioned so far: 1) Don't offer it unless it's wanted, and 2) you can't "fix" everybody. Especially not those who don't want to be fixed.

Comment: Der mond ist blutig indeed.

Comment: "That's the worst-arranged techno I've ever heard!" It's polka; you don't get many accordions in techno.

Comment: @Tetsujin Actually, the only time I tried, I did. Get accordions into techno, that is. I took a Computer Music course in undergrad and did a very AfroCelt-Sound-System inspired sorta world-beat treatment of an Irish jig, and got a friend to do some whistle, bodhran, and concertina. My professor said I needed to use a "better" drum loop; not sure what that says about the fact that I actually recorded the kit myself!...

Comment: I used to go to the Fankfurt Musikmesse every year, right at the height of techno. It still gives me nightmares to this day ;)) Guys with mullets & enormous moustaches playing polka on DX7s retrofitted with accordion button keyboards [I kid you not].

Comment: Re the 'better drum loop' I do recall late 90's back when all this stuff was still new, playing an acoustic drum part [& bass, guitars etc too] then chopping them up & hard quantising, so we could do a rock & roll cover track with perfect tempo/timing that we could then deal with as a "found music" track & fake a new 'pop' groove over it. We made the rock & roll version, never made the modern version, so it just sat on a shelf after that, forever more. I just dug it out & threw it up to soundcloud - https://soundcloud.com/graham-lee-15/cmon-everybody-billy-daydream

Comment: Intent and useful information, I agree those are so important.

Comment: This is such a wise answer. And thank you for not pointing out that I should have said **vocabulary** rather than **grammar**…